# TeamCity for continuous integration with Visual Studio 2010 solutions/projects

Tags: visual-studio-2010, silverlight-4.0, teamcity, teamcity-5.0

I am running TeamCity build 5.1.1 on a virtual machine that also hosts our SVN environment. A team I support has recently made the move from Visual Studio 2008/Silverlight 3.0 to Visual Studio 2010/Silverlight 4.0 and when investigating how to do continuous integration with Visual Studio 2010 solutions/projects, it is not as cut and dried as it appeared to be in Visual Studio 2008. Previously I was using Web Deployment Projects and targeting different Release Configurations in TeamCity, which would use the Web Deployment Project to package/deploy the code to our various environments. However when checking out the new Publish ability in Visual Studio 2010 I cannot find a way to specify which location to deploy to. Does everything need to be done in MSBuild now (in the solution file or maybe the Web project file?). If anyone has any examples of how they've done Continuous Integration using TeamCity and Visual Studio 2010, it would be greatly appreciated as I am coming up blank at the moment.

Comment: Did you end up using Publish or WDP for 2010? I'm in the same boat right now.

Comment: I ended up using WDP. It was very easy and presented the path of least resistance at the time.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to find the following:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=711a2eef-b107-4784-9063-c978edc498cd&displaylang=en

Looks like there is a beta for Web Deployment Projects in VS 2010 at this point. Still interested in if there is a way to ultimately accomplish this using the Publish/Package functionality, as it seems like Microsoft has invested a lot more time into that.

Comment: Great - i'm hanging on pretty bad for this to happen

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio® 2010 Web Deployment Projects - RTW

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=89f2c4f5-5d3a-49b6-bcad-f776c6edfa63&displaylang=en